# Play framework ebean , update only one property of the class

Tags: playframework, ebean

I have a class extended from java.ebean model. How to update only one property of the class?

Comment: Add proper tags to the question: Play version, `ebean`, main language...

Answer (score 1):

Just find the object by `id` and update what's required:

```
MyModel myModel = MyModel.find.byId(id);
myModel.foo = "bar";
myModel.update(id);
```